# Set JTabbedPane width to constant

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I'm implementing an UI in Java Swing.
Therefore I use a `JTabbedPane`.
The tabbedPane has no components at startup. When i add a tab to the tabbedpane, the width of the tabbedpane increases, when i remove the tab, the width resizes to the width at the startup. This should not happen.
The tabbedpane is placed on a `JPanel` which has a gridbag layout.

Layout code:

```
Container contentPane = mainFrame.getContentPane();
contentPane.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();        
// add the component tree
initComponentTree();
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
c.gridheight = 1;
c.gridwidth = 1;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
c.weightx = 1;
c.weighty = 1;
contentPane.add( componentTree, c );        
// add the tabbed pane
initTabbedPane();
c.gridx = 1;
c.weightx = 10;
contentPane.add( tabbedPane, c );       
// add the status panel
initStatusPanel();
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 1;
c.gridwidth = 2;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
c.weightx = 0;
c.weighty = 0;
contentPane.add( statusPanel, c );
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: post some code showing your gridbagconstraints.

Comment: Refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510310/how-to-make-jtabbedpane-autoresize-to-fit-page-dimensions

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `ipadx` value of the `GridBagConstraints` to the desired width.

Comment: This does not work, because `ipadx` defines the padding in x direction.

Answer (score 0):

It has always been my opinion that GridBagLayout should be avoided at all costs. It really offers nothing that can't be achieved by nesting panels with other layouts. The only thing it offers is a lot of frustration.

I would recommend putting your JTabbedPane in a panel using BorderLayout and put it in the CENTER position. If you insist on using GridBayLayout you can try using the setMinimumSize() method, GridBagLayout is one of the layout managers that honors that method (BoxLayout is the other).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [setSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setSize%28int,%20int%29)?

```
JTabbedPane pane;
pane.setSize(SOME_WIDTH_CONSTANT, SOME_HEIGHT_CONSTANT);
```

Comment: -1 setSize is _never_ the answer to layout problems, it's the exclusive task of the LayoutManager