# JTabbedPane in JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I have a simple problem when I want to add tabs in my jpanel. The alignment of the tabs get horizontal instead of vertical, wich looks like crap =/.

It looks like this:

[image]

If I discard the panel instead and add the tabbedPane directly to the frame, everything works fine.
If you uncomment the three lines of code and remove the `getContentPane().add(jtp);` you can reproduce my probleme.

working Code:

```
public class TabbedPane extends JFrame
{
    public TabbedPane()
    {
        setTitle("Tabbed Pane");
        setSize(300, 300); // set size so the user can "see" it
        JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();

        // JPanel panel = new JPanel();//uncomment all three lines
        // panel.add(jtp);
        // getContentPane().add(panel);

        getContentPane().add(jtp);//remove me

        JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();// This will create the first tab
        JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();// This will create the second tab

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setText("This is Tab 1");
        jp1.add(label1);

        jtp.addTab("Tab1", jp1);
        jtp.addTab("Tab2", jp2);

        JButton test = new JButton("Press");
        jp2.add(test);

        setVisible(true); // otherwise you won't "see" it
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TabbedPane tab = new TabbedPane();
    }

}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you just need to set the size:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510310/how-to-make-jtabbedpane-autoresize-to-fit-page-dimensions

Answer (score 4):

> If I discard the panel instead and add the `tabbedPane` directly to the frame, everything works fine.

The default layout of `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`, which "lets each component assume its natural (preferred) size." The default layout of `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`, the `CENTER` of which ignores preferred size. In either case, invoking `setSize()` precludes the layout from functioning initially; re-size the frame to see the effect. Instead, use `pack()`, which "Causes this `Window` to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents."

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
pack();
setVisible(true); // otherwise you won't "see" it
```

Comment: As far as I can follow you, you are right. But anyhow I dont see the relation how this solves my problem. +1 anyway ;)

Comment: @ThomasK: Layout managers are designed to accommodate components of varying size in response to resizing the enclosing window; `pack()` does the initial adjustment. You may have to experiment a little to see the effect; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14555985/230513).

Answer (score 3):

There are many things I would change in that code, starting with the recommendations of @trashgod.  OTOH this is the minimal change needed in order to stretch the tabbed pane to the width/height of the parent container.

```
// give the panel a layout that will stretch components to available space
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());//uncomment all three lines
panel.add(jtp);
getContentPane().add(panel);

//getContentPane().add(jtp);//remove me
```

For more details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181197/418556).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well firstly you can try this:

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();//uncomment all three lines
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();// This will create the first tab
    JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();// This will create the second tab

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
    label1.setText("This is Tab 1");
    jp1.add(label1);

    jtp.addTab("Tab1", jp1);
    jtp.addTab("Tab2", jp2);

    JButton test = new JButton("Press");
    jp2.add(test);
    getContentPane().add(jtp);
```

and in the main:

```
    TabbedPane tab = new TabbedPane();
    tab.pack();
    tab.setVisible(true);
```

May I suggest using [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) to set layouts, it will make your life easier. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try [GridbagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). Once you have mastered it, you can design UI of any sort with this layout.

Comment: *"Once you have mastered it,.."*  Are you a master of GBL? *"you can design UI of any sort"*  Really?  Here's a challenge for you, design a GUI with the same layout as shown in the [Nested Layout Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6755801/418556) using ***only*** GBL.  Don't worry about the titled borders, but replicate the effect of the rest of the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [prasanth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2013044/prasanth) regarding the use of `GridBagLayout`

I have gone through this problem once and I solved it by adding the `JTabbedPane`to the panel via `GridBagLayout`, make sure you add the `JTabbedPane` using the `ipadx` and `ipady` according to your requirements in your `GridBagConstraints` object
e.g.

```
JPanel myPanel=new JPanel();
myPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
JTabbedPane jTP=new JTabbedPane();
jTP.add("Tab1",new JPanel());//substitute your component instead of "new JPanel"
GridBagConstraints myConstraints=new GridBagConstraints();
myConstraints.ipadx=400;//streches the component being added along x axis - 200 px on both sides
myConstraints.ipady=600;//streches the component being added along y axis - 200 px on both sides
myPanel.add(jTP,myConstraints);
```

You can adjust both these properties according to what is perfect for your need